# Best algorithm for age?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

I was wondering what would be the best way to search through a collection with these format:

```
public class Person
{
   public  DateTime Birthdate {get; set;}
}
```

I have the birthdate, I.E 10/10/1943, now let's suppose I have a method that takes two parameters like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> SearchByAgeRange(int AgeMin, int AgeMax)
{
    //Best algorithm goes here.
}
```

The question is how to search over the Person collection in order to get people that whose age is between the MAX and MIN integers passed as parameters?

I am getting stucked!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless your collection is sorted by birthdate, you just have to `foreach` through it and check each person.

Comment: Well, LINQ does have `orderby` in C#...

Comment: Is this LINQ to Objects, or is a connecting to a database at all?

Comment: Thank guys, the problem is not to order the collection, the challenge is within linq discard or take an element whose age is between that range comparing to a datetime...

Comment: @PeterRitchie which would not help here at all. sorting a collection is *O(log n)*, linear search for all items matching given predicate is *O(n)*. Unless you know the collection will already be sorted, I would not go with sorting it explicitly.

Comment: @MRFerocius, edit your post to add in code. We can't read the code in the comments easily.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek LINQ To Objects may be O(n), but not necessarily a database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> SearchByAgeRange(int AgeMin, int AgeMax)
{
    // If the maximum age you are looking for is for instance 80, then you 
    // should look for dates that are greater or equal of the current datetime 
    // minus 80 years. This forms the minDate.
    DateTime minDate = DateTimeNow.AddYears(-AgeMax);

    // If the minimum age you are looking for is for instace 40, then you should 
    // look for dates that are less or equal of the current date minus 40 years.
    // This forms the maxDate.
    DateTime maxDate = DateTimeNow.AddYears(-AgeMin);

    return Persons.Where(x => x.Birthdate >= minDate && x.BirthDate <= maxDate);
}
```

I suppose that `Persons` is a collection of all the persons you have.

Comment: +1 no need to convert every dob to age...just convert the age range to a date range.

Comment: Flawless. Worked as charmed.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you have to figure out how to calculate age using birthday and current date.

```
public static int GetAge(DateTime birthDate)
{
    // your age logic goes here
}
```

Then, you can use LINQ to filter a collection:

```
return from p in people
       let age = GetAge(p.Birthdate)
       where age >= AgeMin && age <= AgeMax
       select p;
```

Comment: Yes, it could be a good idea to make it part of `Person` class. However, I really hope you meant *readonly property*, not *abstract* :)

Comment: Ah yes, readonly not abstract. I get those confused. In my mind, `abstract` means something different than in C#.

Comment: +1 for custom logic for GetAge as sometimes it is necessary to know "how old was the patient when he was examined last time" and DateTimeNow does not make any sense in that case

Answer (score 2):

```
public IEnumerable<Person> SearchByAgeRange(this IEnumerable<Person> personCollection, int AgeMin, int AgeMax)
{
    return personCollection.Where(c=> {
        var currentAge =(((DateTime.Now - c.Birthdate).TotalDays+1) / 365.25);
        return currentAge > AgeMin && currentAge<AgeMax;
    });
}
```